# How to assign a nullable object reference to a non-nullable variable?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I am using VS2019 and has enabled nullable check semantics in project setting. I am trying to get the executable's path using assembly as below:

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        if (assembly == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("cannot find exe assembly");
        }
        var location = new Uri(assembly.GetName().CodeBase);//doesn't compile.
```

It says, "assembly" is a [Assembly?] type, while the Uri ctor requires a string, compilation error is:

```
error CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

How to fix my code to make it compile?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [null-forgiving operator `!`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) to tell the compiler that `CodeBase` can't be `null`

```cs
var location = new Uri(assembly.GetName().CodeBase!);
```

or use a [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) with some default value

```cs
var location = new Uri(assembly.GetName().CodeBase ?? string.Empty);
```

The error

> CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'uriString' in
>   'Uri.Uri(string uriString)'

usually treated as warning, it seems that you've enabled this option in project settings

Comment: One of the nicest operators in 8, great solution.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that [`AssemblyName.CodeBase`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/AssemblyName.cs,63) is nullable: it's of type `string?`.

You need to add extra code to handle the case where `.CodeBase` is `null` (or suppress it with `!`), e.g:

```
var codeBase = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.GetName().CodeBase;
if (codeBase == null)
{
    throw new Exception("cannot find exe code base");
}
var location = new Uri(codeBase);
```

or

```
var location = new Uri(assembly.GetName().CodeBase!);
```

---

The actual warning you get in this case is nothing to do with `assembly`, it's:

> warning CS8604: Possible null reference argument for parameter 'uriString' in 'Uri.Uri(string uriString)'.

[Source](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEA3GUCWAZgJ4A+AAgEwCMAsAFDkAMABOdQHQBKMhANjDAZ8EAHYBuBgwDEogK58+AQ2ACWMUSoENyAZjaUWAYQYBvBi0tt95FCwCyACgCUFq+fpWvLbEqgslAGdAmABbVWIWAF4WAEFgsIiOAHEYDABRUQwoYniQ8L5iF0lPb0siFkcg/IjomPlFV1KyjzKyjAALKAgAdxZRGD70hDAYAAdhMUcAIjAlUVEIDBZCfFEAE3UEGACEguJp5xK2lgBfNzLffz4IOcnRaP7BlgBVAiq9pNSMADklUJgLg4Rgg6xgACEgjAjgB6GHrCAwQKiADky0goTG+AEHAuZwYpyAA===) (expand the "Warnings" pane on the lower right). This tells you that the problem is with the string being passed into the `Uri` constructor, i.e. the string returned from `.CodeBase`.